# How to find database connection information for Oracle on VirtualBox?

Tags: mac-osx, virtualbox, oracle

I am attempting to run an Oracle database on a Mac OS X system. To do so, I have followed the following guide:

https://dimitrisli.wordpress.com/2012/08/08/how-to-install-oracle-database-on-mac-os-any-version/

I have installed VirtualBox and downloaded the most recent Oracle Technology Network Developer Day Database Virtual Box Appliance.

I am able to launch the VirtualBox and Application successfully.

My problem comes when attempting to establish a connection to the database within the VirtualBox itself. When I open SQLDeveloper and attempt to create a new connection using the supplied password and SID (both are stored in a readme.txt file within the VirtualBox), the logon fails. Usernames are not supplied on the VirtualBox (that I can find, anyway). I've been trying oracle and hr, as these are commonly included in the example tutorials.

Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong, what I could do differently or where I can find better documentation?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Failure - Test failed: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Comment: I found some other related Oracle documentation and found that the DBA sign-in username is system. That seems to have worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found some other related Oracle documentation and found that the DBA sign-in username is system. That seems to have worked for me.